# How to create a key ring for Lotus Domino 9.0.1 using CLI?

Tags: windows, certificate, tls

I have an IBM Lotus Domino install on Microsoft Windows. I am looking for the steps I need to follow to create a key ring and CSR for Lotus Domino,but I am unable to find an answer. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Here we may help you with creating keys and certificates (though if you search the web you will find a lit of how-tos). IMHO this question is product based (so I'd guess you will more success posting the question to the IBM dW forum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the steps below :-

1. Create a Keyring file

   `kyrtool ="c:\Program Files\IBM\Notes\notes.ini" create -k "c:\Program Files\IBM\Notes\data\keyring.kyr" -p password`
2. Generate an RSA keypair using OpenSSL

   `openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048`

   The resulting keypair should not be password protected. This isn't a good security practice, so only perform these steps for production systems on a restricted access system believed to be secure. The resulting keypair should look like the following:

   ```
   -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
   MIIJKAIBAAKCAgEAr9uZYZ1BrraxW1AdM1ecexiD2uaPxNKjS2p2p9pygUc/vU2d
   rrqjj3tAybdkNEFcwQLY/eIZcEowHmhH0b9Ut5EOsMMxkB4vUHg6gWmse64wr2qx
   5EmUfjZ/LDMDqnmFxTDvr2iiajZI/L/8thgwBEK2AEGhCppyvyo/mzvMua9j7I8G
   [Many lines removed]
   tuEe3JGUnHaWetQYOU6PmTKIgPpd3disflCJe8K1dzN8bEkQF2eZk/oODVHSHRyC
   7Rw9zpLxTJmbd3iWW3+ZVHhpudYZrDE8NbaaiGMbfyfQBnSH1XbDHSveTxLOY3fo
   +d9lePMThdnmme6b1v8X4sCuDKrFjoV5Veo4Qq8I+099hu3tTRq2zGpNPsg=
   -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
   ```
3. Generate a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) using OpenSSL

   `openssl req -new  -key server.key(Key file name generated in the above command) -out server.csr`

   You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
   into your certificate request.
   What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
   There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
   For some fields there will be a default value,

   ### If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.

   Country Name (2 letter code) [XX]:.
   State or Province Name (full name) []:
   Locality Name (eg, city) [Default City]:.
   Organization Name (eg, company) [Default Company Ltd]:.
   Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:.
   Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) []:www.example.com
   Email Address []:

   Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
   to be sent with your certificate request
   A challenge password []:
   An optional company name []:

   The output will look like the following below

   ```
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
   MIIEbDCCAlQCAQAwJzElMCMGA1UEAwwcdWx0cmF2aW9sZXQuc3dnLnVzbWEuaWJt
   LmNvbTCCAiIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggIPADCCAgoCggIBAK/bmWGdQa62sVtQ
   HTNXnHsYg9rmj8TSo0tqdqfacoFHP71Nna66o497QMm3ZDRBXMEC2P3iGXBKMB5o
   [Many lines removed]
   nbXBaWgJqMk71f2vU1LnNQQresCBJpzNWgjyLaTszUR6eL8JD9WxddMK/82h9QVx
   uFO005u3Fa2uC+8axiMKO3sSuVsgXHQpCuSnw2jDCQoeW/C/GSswsdWVyEzHMMjD
   KQTH5iQLVPWArBoE1SV/RzG8tvLqH6JxHmSG7cnrgH0=
   -----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
   ```

Comment: Hey Nick, Thank you! it worked perfectly for me.